# ie7 hover issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm not great at CSS, I do PHP and Javascript.

However I've had to create a horizontal hover menu for a website that I'm working on. It's working fine in IE6 & IE8, however the sub parts won't appear in IE7. It works in all the proper browsers too.

I've created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianbarker/hnUAy/4/) which replicates the problem. The sub menu seems to appear very briefly (just a quick flash) when I view it in IE7 via parallels.

I've tried Googling for a few hours, but I'm not really sure what the exact issue is, especially because it works in IE6.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
float: none;
```

from

```
div#main-navigation ul li:hover ul li
```

Comment: you beauty! what is this bug know as?

Comment: @ianbarker: No Bug. CSS float property can have values of right or left. A value of "none" does not exist.

Comment: To correct myself, float: none is the deffault value, I think.

Comment: Hmmm, it's in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position); but it works, so I'm not complaining :)

Comment: Yeah! I wonder about that too. Why would it have a none value since it is not inherited either.